# C# : Charts Change using Axis label

Tags: c#, graph, charts, label, axis

I have a chart it looks like this 
[image: http://imgur.com/XoeCnvO]

I want to change Y axis numbering and label it 1% 10% 33.% etc as shown below with out changing the plot.
How do I change it

Required output graph:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cl6K8.jpg[image]

Comment: Post code of how you populate the chart's data points

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489231(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: No, post the code you have, and have actually used to produce the above image.

Comment: Finally got it working

Comment: CustomLabel label1 = new CustomLabel
        {
             FromPosition = y1;//position on axis.
             ToPosition = y2;
             Text = "Y%";//value desired 
        }

Comment: Why do you need the code.I too used the code in the link provided above

Comment: No (real) expressions for Labels, unfortunately. You need CustomLabels.

Comment: its a fixed value and not variable type